# What is the function of `[1]` in program?

Tags: ruby

```
class String
  def mgsub(key_value_pairs=[].freeze)
    regexp_fragments = key_value_pairs.collect { |k,v| k }
    gsub(Regexp.union(*regexp_fragments)) do |match|
      key_value_pairs.detect{|k,v| k =~ match}[1]
    end
  end
end

puts "GO HOME!".mgsub([[/.*GO/i, 'HoMe'], [/home/i, 'is where the heart is']])
puts "Here is number #123".mgsub([[/[a-z]/i, '#'], [/#/, 'P']])
```

Comment: you should elaborate more on your question

Answer (score 0):

`key_value_pairs` is an array of arrays, each a pair. `detect` takes out one element, which is an array (pair). `[1]` takes out the latter (second) value of it.

Comment: why can't I use any other integer in place of 1?